# return json on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I need to return json, send it throw $.get request and show it with .html funtion.
I would prefer dom option, but i have a laravel framework on backend, and i'm still using blade. So i have something like:

```
                $response = [
                    'success'   => true,
                    'content'   => view('/collette/create_step_01', compact('prodotto', 'destinatario', 'input'))->render(),
                ];
```

and i return

```
return json_encode($response);
```

There is a better way for return json on laravel?

On js i have

```
    var qs = getQueryString();

if (typeof(step) === 'undefined') {
    initColletta(); //define step
}

$.get(url + 'collette/create/steps/' + step, qs, function(data) {
    var res = JSON.parse(data);

    if (res.success) {
        showModalBody(res.content);

        if (typeof(res.stop) !== 'undefined' && res.stop) {
            $('#step-next').attr('href', res.link).unbind('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The main problem is that on my vagrant ubuntu box it run WITHOUT any exception. Instead i have that on my production server. any idea??

Answer (score 0):

To return Json in Laravel you should use

```
return response()->json(your_json_here);
```

And as far as the error is concerned that is likely due to the fact that you don't need to Parse the JSON as it is already a valid JSON object.

Comment: what i have to include for "use" response()-> json?

Also is funny becouse the second time that i use that function, it run without prob. but on first start it didnt function.

Comment: You do not need to add anything to use that function out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` is because there is actually an error from the response itself...

Which i will assume to be the first "<" in the view you are returning via json_encode();

I'll suggest you confirm what is being returned first... probably via `var_dump()`.

And of course, another way to return json via laravel like you asked is

```
return response()->json(json_array);
```